# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup

I am using
`code = soup.find('input', {'name': 'url'}).get('value')`
from data
`<input name="url" type="hidden" value="VALUE HERE"/>`
and hosting python telegram bot on heroku

but logs giving error:

```
code = soup.find('input', {'name': 'url'}, {"type": "hidden"}).get('value')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Small code I am running on my pc:

```
import requests
import base64 as b
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = input("ENTER URL: ")

x = requests.get(url)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 
Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = result.content.decode()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

code = soup.find('input', {'name': 'url', 'value': True})['value']
print(code)

str(b.b64decode(code)).strip("'")
                               
exit_url = re.findall("https.*/", str(b.b64decode(code)))[0]
print(exit_url)
```

Where I am doing wrong? code working on my machine!
Now with this code its giving new error on heroku:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Well, if `find` doesn't find the element you're searching for it will return `None` so you're calling `get` on an instance of `NoneType`. You have to check whether the result of `soup.find` is not `None` first, then use `get`.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve]. What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging, any research? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I have updated code in main post